# Overriding and Override in a ASync Class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, overriding

I have a class that is used for various ASyncTasks. Sometimes, I need to hide certain buttons, or views or whatever based upon the Activity or action. The object needing visibility set can vary.

**MyAsyncTask**

```
    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    public ASynceResponse delegate = null;

        public MyAsyncTask() {
          this.delegate = delegate;
          this.mProgressBar = progressBar;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            return; 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject data) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            delegate.processResults(data);
        }


    public interface ASyncResponse {
        void processResults(JSONObject data);
    }

    }
```

I usually call it by:

```
new MyAsyncTask(this, mProgressBar).execute("Something","Something Else",null);
```

Which I pass in a ProgressBar in the Activity  that shows the background action is happening.

**But I want more**. I want to `Overide` my classes `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` to hide/show other items too.

Is that possible?

But I am trying to find a way to Overide the `onPreExecute` to hide anytype (or many types) views.

Is something like this possible?

```
MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(new onPreExecute(
                // hide a view
));
```

Comment: you can have callbacks to the activity from `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` and update views accordingly in activity. `new onPreExecute(` is wrong. You can also update progress bar in activity itself (hide or show)

Comment: But how do I tell onPreExecute *what* I want to do @Raghunandan ?

Comment: ackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui. You know what you should in `onPreExecute` just implement the same in the callback method in activity

Comment: You need another another method in your `ASyncResponse` interface for that.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I am already doing what you suggested in the Link @Raghunandan

Comment: You create an interface that has a callback for `onPreExecute` then you implement that interface for whatever class you want and then in your `AsyncTask` you call the callback which will call the corresponding callback in your class.

Comment: It seems you're doing that for your `onPostExecute` only with `delegate.processResults(data)`, do it in your `onPreExecute` as well

Comment: check the answer i posted

Comment: @user-44651 pls elaborate what i don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do that using interface.**

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

   private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
   public ASynceResponse delegate = null;

       public MyAsyncTask() {
         this.delegate = delegate;
         this.mProgressBar = progressBar;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
          delegate.myOnPreExecute();
          mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }

       @Override
       protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
           return; 
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject data) {
           mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           delegate.processResults(data);
       }


       public interface ASyncResponse {
           void processResults(JSONObject data);
           void myOnPreExecute();
       }

   }
```

> Demo class example

```
class Demo implements ASyncResponse{
      .....
      void processResults(JSONObject data){
      ....
      }
      void myOnPreExecute(){
        // do your stuff for pre execute
      }

   }
```

Comment: Oh ok! I didn't think about just creating another delegate method call.